# Lombok: Apply "var" for all local variable declarations automatically

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, var, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

[Lombok has a neat feature to use var instead of local variable datatype declarations](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/var). Is there a way to "refactor" your entire code base automatically to use `var` whenever applicable? I'm using [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and the [`Lombok plugin`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin). I didn't find a feature like this.

Also, does it even make sense since `var` is still considered "experimental" so it might "mess up" the code base when it gets deprecated/is somehow bugged/gets replaced/moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Moreover, I wouldn't recommend this.

- Being explicit is always better so IMHO `var` is only good when the cost of being explicit is too high. This is only the case with lengthy LHS where the same information is repeated on the RHS.
- Use diamond operator (or factories). Not that `var list = new ArrayList<>()` can't work as you removed the type parameters from both sides.
- Prefer `val` to `var`. With `val` not being longer than `var`, there's no reason not to use it (unlike when separate `final` is needed). This way, you can see what variables may change.

I'd bet the Lombok authors would agree with me, so they won't support such a feature. I hope the same holds for the plugin author.

Comment: A list can work with e.g. `var list = new ArrayList<String>()` though but you're right, it would break type safety

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Sure, it can, but writing this is hardly shorter than `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()` and it removes the information from the more important place.

Comment: Very soon, java will support `var` out-of-the-box. I see no reason not to start using it already from lombok.